# classes and data presentation

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I hope someone can give me some guidance in how to best approach this situation.
I am using dbcontext, wpf and sql server.
I am having situations were the presentation of the data requires other data than just what is coming from a single table. For example, if I had a person table but wanted to show also how many books they had read from related data, say fields would be name, address, NoOfBooks.
I currently create a new class, called say PersonBookPM, that I fill up with data from a linq query which combines the two tables which includes the above three fields.I create an observablecollection of that and make that the itemssource of the grid/listbox.
When I am then adding data to that I then need to use the selecteditem, convert that back to the single entity of person, and attach it back in to the context.
It seems like the classes have already been defined by the code gen and I am repeating the process only slightly differently.
Am I going round the houses here?
Thanks Scott

Comment: You are not repeating process. You don't want just those autogenerated classes - you want classes with additional details (projections/views) and if you want to save data back you need to decompose your projections back to entities which EF can save.

Comment: fair enough. I am on the correct tracks then. Thanks for confirmation. Thats all I needed.Scott